# Does two orthogonally polarized light beams interfere?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

If we have x and y polarized light do they interfere, if they have a phase difference?

Comment: What do $you$ think?

Comment: I think they will superimpose to form an elliptically polarized light, depending on the phase difference of x and y polarization we can know if it is right elliptical or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to see any interference fringes when you superimpose two optical beams with orthogonal states of polarization. However, if you use another polarizer to extract a mutual state of polarization from both these beams, then you will be able to see interference fringes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lights to be coherent, yes they will. But the shape of the net electric field will depend on their phase difference. For example, if the phase difference is 0 or 180, you will get a linearly polarized light. If the phase difference is anything else, you will get an elliptically polarized light.

Comment: wouldn't we call that just superposition and not interference?

Comment: @AnanthR  In physics, interference is a phenomenon in which two waves superpose to form a resultant wave of greater, lower, or the same amplitude. This is from wikipedia

Comment: @ Rishibh Jain  This means superposition is a superset of Interference.